# Best way to check if a bucket is ready in node.js

Tags: node.js, docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-storage, gcsfuse

I'm using **gcsfuse** to mount a volume in a container, and I need it to start my node.js application.

To mount the volume I'm using the **lifecycle hooks of kubernetes**, but it doesn't ensure that it will be executed before the entrypoint of my container.

I've been thinking about how should I check when the volume is mounted, and if it goes down.

To check when it is mounted and unmounted I read and search the existence of the volume in `/proc/mounts`, and adding a watcher to it for changes.

Is there a simplier way to ensure that the volume is mounted in node.js, docker, or kubernetes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run this dockerfile in privileged mode:

```
FROM ubuntu 
RUN echo "deb http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt gcsfuse-stretch main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/gcsfuse.list 
RUN apt-get update && apt install curl -y 
RUN curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | apt-key add - 
RUN apt-get update 
RUN apt-get install gcsfuse fuse -y 
RUN mkdir -p /mnt/tmp 
CMD gcsfuse [BUCKET NAME] /mnt/tmp && /bin/bash
```

This way you are sure that the bucket is mounted when the pod initializes.

On the other hand I do not recommend this approach as there is a Node.sj library for Google Cloud Storage [1].

Here is an example of bucket listing:

```
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');

// Creates a client
const storage = new Storage();

// Lists all buckets in the current project
storage
  .getBuckets()
  .then(results => {
    const buckets = results[0];

    console.log('Buckets:');
    buckets.forEach(bucket => {
      console.log(bucket.name);
    });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('ERROR:', err);
  });
```

[1] https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/tree/master/samples

Comment: You're right. I though it would be easier to handle gcs as standard filesystem, but it wasn't.